# Extract first variable from another variable

Tags: command-line, dns

I have a .bat script that does some ping, nslookup and other commands on a list of hostnames.
Somewhere down the line, I get a variable %FQDN%, which echoes out the fqdn of the remote machine, however i only need the hostname from the %FQDN% variable to compare it to the original hostname used.

I put a list of hostnames in a file called list.txt. (pc1, pc2, pc3) all on a new line.
That hostname is then %1, which i need to check if it is = to the hostname in the %FQDN% variable?

any suggestions on how i would accomplish this?

I vaguely remember there was some command something about qback or something that could do this... but i don't know how it should be used.

The main script that does the ping, dnslookup and stuff looks like so:
Many of the echos will be removed at a later stage, once i am happy that everything works as supposed to.

```
    @echo off
@cls

:: **************************************************
::
:: Just grabs the machine names from a list and then
:: calls another subroutine, passing the name to the
:: routine.
::
:: **************************************************

:getName

  for /f %%a in (list.txt) do call :doIt %%a

  goto end

:: **************************************************
::
:: The %1 is the %%a from the previous routine. In this
:: case you get the machine name. It is being set
:: as a variable for ease of use in the rest of the
:: script.
::
:: So now you copy the file out to the system and
:: and verify it is there. The IF statement defines
:: a variable to be used for logging and to determine
:: whether or not to waste time running PSEXEC against
:: a machine where the file failed to copy.
::
:: So now we say if the var strFil = "ok", go ahead
:: and run PSEXEC. If not, then go log what you have
:: so far.
::
:: I would include some kind of error checking after
:: running REGSVR32 to verify the file was registered
:: and then log that as well.
::
:: **************************************************

:doIt

  set strSvr=%1

PING %1 -n 1| FIND /i "TTL" > nul && goto Success
PING %1 -n 1| FIND /i "timed" > nul && goto Timedout
PING %1 -n 1 -w 400 | FIND /i "TTL" > nul || goto ErrorMsg
goto :EOF

:Success
cls
echo Ping command was successful
echo Now we are setting the IP and HostName variable

for /F "tokens=3" %%a in ('ping %1 ^| find /i "TTL"') do set Address=%%a
for /F "tokens=2" %%a in ('ping -a %Address::=% ^| find /i "pinging"') do set FQDN=%%a

set IPAddress=%Address::=%
cls
echo.
echo %1
echo %IPAddress%
echo %FQDN%
echo.
echo above is just to confirm that hostname,IP and FQDN is set
echo.
pause
cls
echo now we do a NSLOOKUP on the IPAddress collected from PING.
for /f "tokens=2" %%a in ('nslookup %IPAddress% ^| find /i "Name: " ') do set nsNAME=%%a
echo.
pause
cls
echo now we confirm that original hostname = FQDN
echo using NSLOOKUP details from previous commands
echo.
pause
cls
echo nsname
echo %nsNAME%
echo.
echo var 1
echo %1
echo.
echo strSvr
echo %strSvr%
echo.
echo FQDN
echo %FQDN%
pause
cls

if "%1"=="%FQDN%" (
set hnstatus="HOSTNAME is GOOD fix will be run"
) else (
set hnstatus="HOSTNAME is BAD we cannot do anything"
)
echo %hnstatus%
echo.
echo Hostname status above = GOOD or bad
echo if bad, then hostname resolves to different IP.
echo.
cls
pause

::exit


echo %strSvr%
echo just checking if we still have a machine name as a variable.
pause
cls
echo.
echo Now we need to start the copy process and run wmifix remotely.
echo.
pause

:: if "%nsname%"=="%Hostname%" (
:: echo f | xcopy /f /Y "wmifix.bat" "\\%strSvr%\c$\Temp\fallout\wmifix.bat"
:: psexec \\%strSvr% c:\Temp\fallout\wmifix.bat
:: ) else (
:: echo Hostname is bad cannot do anything
:: set hnstatusbad="Hostname is bad cannot do anything"
:: )

  goto logIt

:: **************************************************
:: 
:: LOGS ARE IMPORTANT!!
:: Get in the habit of logging the results of your
:: scripts. Verify the important pieces so you know
:: what has been completed and what you have to chase
:: down.
:: 
:: **************************************************

:Timedout
Echo %1, Request timed out.
Echo %1, Request timed out. >> fallouts_log.csv
goto :EOF

:ErrorMsg
Echo %1, Ping request could not find host.
Echo %1, Ping request could not find host. >> fallouts_log.csv
goto :EOF



:logIt

  echo.%strSvr%,%hnstatus%,%hnstatusbad%>>fallouts_log.csv
pause
:end
```

and then list.txt just contains hostnames like this:

```
DT048035
DT040676
```

Sample of %FQDN%

DT048035.za.lacer.net

i only want to check if first part before first . is the same as any of the other hostname variables %1 or %strSvr% (which is only DT048035)

Comment: can this question be boiled down to "I have a list of strings in a text file and I need to test if %FQDN% matches any of them"?

Comment: Take a look at FINDSTR (http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)

Comment: [FOR /F Loop command: against the results of another command](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) shows how to use "usebackq". If you edit your post to include your batch file I can take a look at how you can do this. Please also include a copy of list.txt (suitably censored if necessary)

Comment: @rob no, i do not think that it can be boiled down as you suggested, as that is not what i am looking for. I have added the actual script and list of hostnames.

Comment: @duDE i took a look at FINDSTR, but could not figure out how i would implement it into my main script.

Comment: @DavidPostill I have added to script, also tried looking into the FOR /F loop, but cannot figure out how to implement it. :(

Comment: Please edit your question to include some examples of what %FQDN% looks like.

Comment: @DavidPostill sample has been added.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
**names.txt**
host1
host2
host3

**check.bat**
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /p name=Enter the host name 
FINDSTR /L /C:%name% names.txt
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 echo "found" ELSE echo "not found"
pause
```

Comment: You can modify the script to set the value of name to some other variable instead of prompting it from the user